# Excel - Format active cell based on content

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets in my workbook.  In the first sheet, I have 10 columns with the numbers 1 through 1000.  Specific numbers have specific formats (colored, bold, whatever).

In the second sheet, I want to be able to enter a value into any cell, on any row or column and have it look up the value I enter, check the first sheet for the value I've entered, and copy its format.

Is this at all possible?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it would require a VBA subroutine (macro) that responds to the `Worksheet_Change` event. It would need to:

- Loop through the cells that were just edited (there may be more than one)
- Obtain the value of the cell
- Find the cell on the other worksheet that has that number
- Either copy the source cell and Past Special, Format Only, or manually update the formatting options you want to copy from one cell to the other.

Comment: Aaaaand... How would I go about that :)  As I mentioned... Excel illiterate here.  I can fumble my way through some small code changes and stuff if I spend oodles of time on it.  But struggling to find code that will do what I'm asking.  Any pointers to some sites?  Or some examples that I could begin to tear apart for what i'm trying to do?  Cheers!